# Python: Remove item from dictionary in functional way

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I've been programming in Python for quite a while now. I've always wondered, is there a way to remove an item from a dictionary and return the newly created dictionary? Basically removing an item from a dict in a functional way.

As far as I know, there are only the `del dict[item]` and `dict.pop(item)` methods, however both modify data and don't return the new dict.

Comment: You can indeed remove an item from a `Map` like type in a functional way but you need an implementation based on a persistent data structure. Persistent data structures are implemented as balanced trees, a Red-Black-Tree for instance. More complex ones rely on finger trees or tries, namely hashed array mapped tries. A persisntant data structure only copies the path from the root to the modified leaf and shares the rest of the structure. Since the underlying tree is balanced, this approach allows efficient updates/lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way for dicts, you have to do it yourself. Something to the effect of:

```
>>> data = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
>>> data
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k != item}
```

Note, Python 3.9 *did* add a `|` operator for dicts to create a new, merged dict:

```
>>> data
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> more_data = {"b":4, "c":5, "d":6}
```

Then

```
>>> data | more_data
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6}
```

So, similar to `+` for list concatenation. Previously, *could* have done something like:

```
>>> {**data, **more_data}
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6}
```

Note, `set` objects support operators to create new sets, providing operators for various basic set operations:

```
>>> s1 = {'a','b','c'}
>>> s2 = {'b','c','d'}
>>> s1 & s2 # set intersection
{'b', 'c'}
>>> s1 | s2 # set union
{'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'}
>>> s1 - s2 # set difference
{'a'}
>>> s1 ^ s2 # symmetric difference
{'a', 'd'}
```

This comes down to API design choices.

Comment: Might not be the accepted answer but I appreciate you pointing out the 3.9 operators, I wasn't aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use dict.copy() to create a copy then to do your operations.

For Example:

```
initial_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
dict_copy = initial_dict.copy()
# Then you can do your item operations
del dict_copy["a"]
# or
dict_copy.pop("b")
```

Comment: That would have been my got to as well, but that's a lot of code for one operation. Is there any alternative?